# Set should_remove_source_branch to true is not reflected

Tags: python-gitlab

with python-gitlab I can create and update merge requests in GitLab.

However there is not much documentation on how to tick the "Delete source branch"

I tried with

```
mr.attributes['should_remove_source_branch'] = True
```

and with

```
mr.should_remove_source_branch(True)
```

which does not cause any error but there is no change to the merger request after

```
mr.save()
```

How to correctly set the "Delete source branch" tick ?

Answer (score 0):

for those finding the question.

it looks like there is kind of a bug in gitlab as the code below just works and no additional step is needed for the setting on other projects

```
project.mergerequests.create({'source_branch': branch,
                                   'remove_source_branch': True,
                                   'target_branch': 'main',
                                   'title': title,
                                   'labels': ['license']})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the additional command:

```
mr.save(remove_source_branch=True)
```

Comment: thanks for that. Actually my answer worked fine